# Gradle task to organize import

Tags: java, gradle

I'm searching for a gradle task to organize imports in my java project (all sourcesets),like in Eclipse when you use the command source -> organize import

But what I need is a simple, little plugin to do this exact job, nothing more

As example like this project: https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-imports but is not mantained anymore.

Note: I've also considereted Spotless, but I have discarted it, because I need a simple tool to the job, not a tool with many functionalities

Comment: Did you consider [Spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle) as suggested in the link you gave?

Comment: yes, but Spotless does a lot of other things, and I wanted a specialized and simple tool to do the job I want, not all the package. ( edited request to specify more this )

Comment: I don't understand your requirements for a "specialized tool". With Spotless, you add the plugin, configure it with `removeUnusedImports()` and it will do this and only this. But in any case, I don't personally know of any other tools for it.

Comment: I wish there was a tool to expand `import x.y.*` before I make my changes!

Comment: @BjørnVester spotless doesn't work well for import ordering